# After every 1s, some of the boxes should change the color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have drawn some stars by using javascript on canvas. But I want a few of the stars to fade in and out as well as change the color (red). I attached my Code. I tried to find the solution here but couldn't get it. Would it be possible to make a few of the stars to fade in and out after every 2 seconds by using javascript or jQuery?

```js
const Star = function(x, y, z) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  // this.z = z
  this.size = 3;
};

var context = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

var stars = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
  stars[i] = new Star(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * 400);
}

function loop() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

  height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

  context.canvas.height = height;
  context.canvas.width = width;

  context.fillStyle = "#212524";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    let star = stars[i];
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(star.x, star.y, star.size, star.size)
    myMove();
  }

  function myMove() {
    let id = null;
    let pos = 0;
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
      for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        let star = stars[i];
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fillRect(star.x, star.y, star.size, star.size)
      }
    }
  }
}

loop();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Why do you need `clearInterval(id)`? You just set `id = null` a couple of lines earlier, so there's nothing to clear.

Comment: Either use `requestAnimationFrame()` or `setInterval()`, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
function loop() {

  height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  
  context.canvas.height = height;
  context.canvas.width = width;

  context.fillStyle = "#212524";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    let star = stars[i];
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(star.x, star.y, star.size, star.size)
    myMove();
  }

  function myMove() {
    let id = null;
    let pos = 0;
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(frame, 1000);
    
    function frame() {
        for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
            let star = stars[i];
            context.fillStyle = "white";
            context.fillRect(star.x, star.y, star.size, star.size)
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            let star = stars[Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)];
            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.fillRect(star.x, star.y, star.size, star.size)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi, i trying to create a new using **jquery**.
the stars will be **spread randomly inside a parent element**, also with the **probability to get a different size** of each star is *big 9%, medium 49%, small 52%*, and **probability to get blink** 15%. 
for stars that get blink will be animated by css, **2 seconds and change color to red** when animation reaches 100% progress. if something doesn't work correctly, let me know in the comment section. thanks

```js
function randomNumber(min, max) {  
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
}

function generateStars(elm, parent){
  // get parent size, elm will randomly spread inside the parent
  let scH = parent.height(), scW = parent.width();
  elm
  .css({
    'left': randomNumber(0, scW),
    'top' : randomNumber(0, scH)
  })
  .appendTo(parent);
  // probability the size of this star
  // big 9%, medium 49%, small 52%
  let ssize = randomNumber(0, 100);
  elm.addClass( ssize>90?"big":ssize>50?"medium":"small" );
  // probability to this star blinking, 15%
  if( randomNumber(0, 100) >= 85 ){
    elm.addClass('blinking');
  }
}
// generate 50 stars inside #parent
for(let a=0;a<50;a++){
  generateStars( $('<i></i>'), $('#parent') );
}
```

```css
#parent{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:#000;
}
#parent>i{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:2px;
  height:2px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#fff;
}
#parent>i.small{
  width:1px;height:1px;
}
#parent>i.medium{
  width:2px;height:2px;
}
#parent>i.big{
  width:4px;height:3px;
}
#parent>i.blinking {
  animation: blink 2s step-start infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  50%{opacity: .5;}
  50%{opacity: 1;background:red;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"></div>

<!--
I have drawn some stars by using javascript on canvas. But I want a few of the stars to fade in and out as well as change the color (red). I attached my Code. I tried to find the solution here but couldn't get it. Would it be possible to make a few of the stars to fade in and out after every 2 seconds by using javascript or jQuery?
-->
```